# Kaa Server and Client Profile

Tags: iot, kaa

I am exploring the features and architecture of Kaa for one of my project requirements. I am able to create independently Client profile and Server profile. 
Can anyone give a real time example and suggest me

Comment: Have you gone through the [key platform features](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Endpoint-profiles/)?

Comment: Yes I have gone through the profile pages and sample examples. I do understand that Client side profile can be used to map to edge. However, I don't understand how the Logged and Profiles are related (or even are they related?) I do understand that I can update profile. But How frequently can it be updated? (Like my need is, 100 updates per second). Is it possible? Also, How do I fetch the current data that is available to profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no restrictions on the frequency of a profile update. The obvious limitations come from the API used for its data fetch, etc.

For example, the profile data can be (requires simple configuration) passed to a Custom Log Appender together with the telementry comming from Data Collection feature. Also, one can update the Server side profile directly from there with REST API.

As per the original question, you should provide more information on the use case and what are you trying to achieve with use of Client/Server profiles.

Comment: Hello, My use case is : I have a data generator (an application preferably running on an Embedded board) that collects the sensor data (e.g. temperature) every second. I want to do data modelling and updating on Kaa server for this. How do I achieve this? Also, If I use Client profile, is there a way (other than generating notifications or events) to know is profile is updated?

Comment: What modeling do you need? Please add more details.
Client profile is updated from the endpoint (client) side only. Then, when it is received on the Kaa server, there are few points where the update is visible. Client profile is used within Endpoint Grouping logic, so you can setup some Configuration change for a profile update (if that fits your needs). Also, the Client profile can be configured to be passed to a Log Appender. That is, a Log Appender will be provided with Client profile data for each Data Collection log record. See Custom Log Appender in documentation.